# add an index file or an .htaccess file for each directory?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Ok so my current sites is on the `.htaccess` method to block user access to the directory
e.g. `http://www.example/_directory/` via `Options All -Indexes`

Question should I stick with that or is putting an index file e.g. `index.php` in every directory better? I'm thinking of an `index.php` that will redirect to the homepage rather than giving users an error 403 page.

Opinions?

Comment: Please add `.htaccess` file content here ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be clever to build your web site in a way that these subdirectories also have content (e.g. about/ also shows some information, when about/history/ and about/our-company/).

If the directories contain only files, it's IMHO totally fine to just have a 403.

Answers to your questions might be very biased.

Comment: all my subdirectories are files e.g. `css, js, images, etc.` main content are all in the maindirectory so I guess i'll stick with `.htaccess` route. thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I would just not care about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Unix/Linux server, you don't need to have blank index files at all in your directories. Just create a .htaccess file and put the following code in it:

Code:

```
Options -Indexes
```

When anyone tries to access the contents of a directory that doesn't have an index file, they'll get a 403 error.

Ref : http://wildlifedamage.unl.edu/manual/mod/core.html#options